# Why do messages go to spam when sent using the Graph?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

When i send am email using the graph, it ends up in junk / spam of any office 365 inbox. But when i send directly from the browser it goes to inbox.

here's an example of the request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendMail
Content-type: application/json

{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "fannyd@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "ccRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "danas@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveToSentItems": "false"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to Repro the same sample in my lab and I am getting mail in my **Inbox**.

Check this [link](https://www.howtogeek.com/290046/how-to-stop-legitimate-emails-from-getting-marked-as-spam/) to Stop Legitimate Emails From Getting Marked as Spam.